# Removed empty array element to json_encode after

Tags: php, json, array-difference, array-filter

I have simple array

```
$a = ['a', '', 'b','c','d'];
```

if i **json_encode** it i ll have

```
["a","","b","c","d"]
```

But if i ll try to remove empty value, with **array_filter** or **array_diff**

i ll have

```
{"0":"a","2":"b","3":"c","4":"d"}
```

but i dont need array keys to be encoded, i need an encoded array without empty elements and without array keys, how to solve?

Php sandbox example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/91635a5df7fcd954dd64fe92089f2beadc81c3c4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$a = array_values(array_filter($a));
```

This resets the keys of your array to be sequential. Consider how the array keys work:

```
$a = ['a', 'b'];       // [0 => 'a', 1 => 'b']
unset($a[0]);          // [1 => 'b']
$a = array_values($a); // [0 => 'b']
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm, you answered first so i mark as answer

Answer (score 4):

This resets the array keys

```
$a = ['a', '', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
echo json_encode(array_values(array_filter($a)));
```